# How to use Vector3.MoveToward() making PianoTiles Type Game Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d, game-physics, translate-animation

I am trying to make a Piano Tiles type game in unity. So I have 6 empty gameobjects(targetGrid[0-5]) which are the targets of my tiles. I am sending my first tiles to first target[0], after reaching targetGrid[0] I'm making the new target to targetGrid[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZFKEA.png) and so on.

But the problem is the speed of my tile is slower from targetGrid[0]-targetGrid[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZFKEA.png) than the others like:

```
speedOf targetGrid[1-2]
= speedOf targetGrid[2-3]
= speedOf targetGrid[3-4]
= speedOf targetGrid[4-5]
>>> speedOf targetGrid[0-1]
```

here is a video of the problem :
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=20pwdbaw0aQ

See, the heart is slow at first. Then It gets faster.

Why is that ?? And how can i solve this problem.

Here is my code and screenShot:

[image]

```
public class CollectiblesMovement : MonoBehaviour {

    public List<Transform> gridPos = new List<Transform> ();

    //public bool middleCrossed = false;

    //public CollectableTypes collectableTypes;

    public CollectibleManager collectableManager;
    private int currentGridNo = 0;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        transform.position = new Vector3 (gridPos[0].position.x,gridPos[0].position.y);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        if(currentGridNo<5)
        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards (transform.position, gridPos [currentGridNo+1].position, collectableManager.collectable_speed*Time.deltaTime);
        if (transform.position == gridPos [Mathf.Clamp((currentGridNo+1),0,5)].position) {
            if (currentGridNo < 5) {
                Debug.Log ("calling " + currentGridNo + " Grid");
                MakeNextObjectGo ();
            }
            else {
                Debug.Log ("calling ManagerFunction");
                currentGridNo = 0;
                transform.position = new Vector3 (gridPos[currentGridNo].position.x, gridPos[currentGridNo].position.y);
            }
        }
    }

    public void MakeNextObjectGo()
    {
        currentGridNo++;
        collectableManager.WhichGridCrossedGridCrossed (transform);
    }

    public void StartAgain()
    {
        collectableManager.FinishedMoving (transform);
    }
}
```

See the movement speed is not same in the grids.

Comment: I fail to understand your question, could you try to be more clear or illustrate the problem? Especially the `speedOf targetGrid[1-2]=speedOf targetGrid[2-3]=speedOf targetGrid[3-4]=speedOf targetGrid[4-5] >>> speedOf targetGrid[0-1]` part. My best guess is that the MoveTowards is moving different objects at different speeds? Is that correct?

Comment: actually speed of my Gameobject changes while change the target. Why is that. And the problem is change of speed is not linear. For first target the speed is lower(e.g : 2units for target 0 to 1) for rest other targets the speed is different to the 1st one(e.g : 5 units for target 2 to target 5). 
Hope, it is clear now :)
TIA : )

Comment: is `collectableManager.collectable_speed` changed during runtime?

Comment: no. I am not changing it during runtime :(

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=20pwdbaw0aQ

Here is the video of the problem :( 
See the heart is slow at first. Then It gets faster.

Comment: If you don't spawn more than 1, does it speed up?

Comment: It only speeds up when i make the target a fixed one.
i mean if i don't change the targer by making it gridPos[5] instead of gridPos[currenGridNo+1] then it is works actually. But i need to change the target in runtime :(

Comment: I feel like you're shooting yourself in the foot with the way you decided to structure it. I would advice you to break up the logic, and encapsulate it into appropriate classes. So a `Tile` would be a class responsible for telling you if you pressed it. `GridBuilder` would construct the tiles in a grid. `ScrollManager` would scroll the grid upwards. It would be much easier to work on the problem this way.